# how to find empty array elements in array and if elements is empty then how to assign the previous database value from the database

Tags: php

this is my code here i am fetching value from data base i want if get empty value in request from front end then i assigned previous value of database of that column

```
$data=array(
        'currentvoltage'=>$this->post('currentvoltage'),
        'mainstatus'=>$this->post('main'),
        'dgstatus'=>$this->post('dg'),
        'acstatus'=>$this->post('acstatus'),
        'firestatus'=>$this->post('fire'),
        'smpsstatus'=>$this->post('smps'),
        'simulatorid'=>$this->post('simulatorId')
       );
      //print_r($data);exit;
       $checkdata=$this->basic->updatedata('tbl_simulatoralert',$data,$this->post('simulatorId'));
      // print_r($checkdata);exit;
       if(!empty($checkdata))
       {

       $response_data['responseCode']    = "200";
       $response_data['responseMessage'] = "Data updated sucessfully";
       $this->response($response_data);
       }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your problem statement isn't clear.

Comment: actually i want to find out empty elements form the array. and the value of these array input dynamically so if user does not input any value then it upadate the value in database of its default value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$data=array(
    'currentvoltage'=>$this->post('currentvoltage'),
    'mainstatus'=>$this->post('main'),
    'dgstatus'=>$this->post('dg'),
    'acstatus'=>$this->post('acstatus'),
    'firestatus'=>$this->post('fire'),
    'smpsstatus'=>$this->post('smps'),
    'simulatorid'=>$this->post('simulatorId')
);
```

Do:

```
$data = array();

if(!empty($this->post('currentvoltage'))) $data['currentvoltage'] = $this->post('currentvoltage');
```

If you have only columns with values in array, only those columns will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$data` stores the inputs received from form:

```
$data = array(
    'currentvoltage'=>$this->post('currentvoltage'),
    'mainstatus'=>$this->post('main'),
    'dgstatus'=>$this->post('dg'),
    'acstatus'=>$this->post('acstatus'),
    'firestatus'=>$this->post('fire'),
    'smpsstatus'=>$this->post('smps'),
    'simulatorid'=>$this->post('simulatorId')
);
```

and let `$db_data` has the data for given id, you can use ternary operator to set values in `$data`.

For example,

```
$data = array(
    'currentvoltage'=>($this->post('currentvoltage')) ?: $db_data['currentvoltage'],

    //similarly others
);
```

It is simple checking for empty/null values and subsituting the input value or value stored in database.